# Writing to a file from a void method

Tags: java, return, void, printwriter

I am working on a program that uses Dijkstra's algorithm and records the results to a text file. The bit of code I have that writes to the file looks like this:

```
try (PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(filename + "Out.txt")) {
                pr.println("Adjacency Matrix: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms ");
                pr.println("Min-Heap: ");
                pr.println("Fibonnaci Heap:");
                pr.println("Dijkstra Adjacency Matrix");
                pr.println(g.printPath(END));
    }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

I have no problems with this bit of code, except for the line g.printPath(END). The error I receive is "void type not allowed here". I fully understand what this means. It occurs because the printPath method is void. It looks like this:

```
public void printPath(String end) {
    if (!graph.containsKey(end)) {
        System.err.printf("End vertex is not contained within graph \"%s\"\n", end);
        return;
    }

    graph.get(end).printPath();
    System.out.println();

}
```

Since I need access to the variable it would print, I tried to modify it to have a return type that I could write to the text file. What I came up with was this:

```
public String printPath(String end) {
    if (!graph.containsKey(end)) {
        System.err.printf("End vertex is not contained within graph \"%s\"\n", end);
        return null;
    }

    graph.get(end).printPath();
    System.out.println();
    return graph.get(end).printPath();

}
```

This again has errors, since the method is of type string but graph.get(end).printPath() is void (the get method is also void). I have attempted returning other variables such as graph and graph.get(end) but they do not return the actual variables inside the graph. I know that graph.get(end).printPath() prints out the correct values I want. I am just struggling to find a way to store them. Is there an easy way I can write this to the text file that I am overlooking without having to go back and edit all of my methods to make them not void? Thanks!

Comment: What is the return instance of graph.get(end) ?

Comment: get() is a method in Map.java and graph.get(end) doesn't print any value, the method, I believe, just gets the values in the path from the beginning to end node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it by redirect`System.out.print`:

```
public String printPath(Graph graph, String end) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(bos);
    //set output stream to bos to capture output
    System.setOut(printStream);

    graph.get(end).printPath(); //your output
    System.out.println();

    //reset output stream to file descriptor
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
    return bos.toString();
}
```

1. Redirect the `System.out` to `ByteArrayOutputStream`,
2. Start print
3. Reset the `System.out` to `FileDescriptor`

Finally, Really don't suggestion do it, it's dirty code and important it's **not thread-safe**, and it's confusing. There is a suggestion about how to deal this:

- Create a method to formatt `graph.get(end)` and return correct `String` type path

Answer (score 1):

With  your current usage, `printPath` shouldn't be printing anything: maybe you could even rename it to `getPath`. You need to build a string with the correct value and return it, so that the returned value can be passed to `println`.

```
public String printPath(String end) {
    if (!graph.containsKey(end)) {
        return "End vertex is not contained within graph \"%s\"\n", end);
    }

    // Also rework this to return a string instead of printlning stuff.    
    return graph.get(end).printPath();
}
```

Alternatively, don't pass the value to `println` and just call `g.printPath(END);` directly.

```
try (PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(filename + "Out.txt")) {
     pr.println("Adjacency Matrix: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms ");
     pr.println("Min-Heap: ");
     pr.println("Fibonnaci Heap:");
     pr.println("Dijkstra Adjacency Matrix");
     g.printPath(END);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but in the first case, if the method is left void, then it produces an error because the second return value is unexpected. If you make it a type, say String, it also produces an error because the return statement is still of type void. In the alternative case, g.printPath(END) doesn't write to the file, it just outputs it to the system.

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed changing the return type to String, fixed now. As the comment in my snippet says, you also need to change printPath to return a String instead of outputting straight to a PrintStream (System.out)